# Python Priority Queue for node

Tags: python, data-structures

So I found the heapq implementation, but that does not seem to work for my purposes. I need a priority queue where the priority is given by a function manhattan_distance(node, end_node) that stores the node. Heapq seems to only work for integers and gives no way to store the nodes?

What is my best option for implementing this without having to write my own class?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out. I can use PriorityQueue from the Queue class. I didn't realize you could put tuples into it.

Sorry!